# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'x' of object '#<Object>' React/JEST

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, babel-jest

While I am writing test case for my react component I am getting

**TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'x' of object '#'**

wherein while the application run it does not throw similiar error

*The code for it is pretty basic*

> this.props.defaultForm = true;

**Why the behavior is different for test and actual application RUN?**

**What would be work around if I want to write a test case?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a way to accomplish that;

Create a "*clone*" of your object with [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method, or JavaScript [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)

`let clone = Object.assign({}, this.props);`

or

`let clone = { ...this.props };`

Then, change the values you need and return the clone as a result.

```
let clone = Object.assign({}, this.props);
clone.defaultForm = true;
return clone;
```

But take into account that Object.assign() creates a shallow copy of an object. Thus, if you need to have a deep copy, I would recommend to use following approach:

```
let deepClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props));
deepClone.defaultForm = true;
return deepClone;
```

Here, "stringifying" the object and then parsing it back will create completely new deeply cloned copy of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Following up to `syntax-punk` answer.

JavaScript has inbuilt function to create an deep copy of any object.

```
const copiedObject = structuredClone(existingObject);
```

Also,

```
let clone = { ...this.props }; //This doesn't create deep copy❌
```

Spread operator in JavaScript doesn't create deep copy of an object

Answer (score -2):

You cannot change the properties of a component. it is in read only.

If you want to can change it. You must use `connect` from `redux` and the function `mapStateToProps`.

You can find more information here: https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-container-components

Comment: Hi Damien, point noted but I am struggling to understand why it works when I run the application but fails while executing the test.

Comment: Do you use `this.prop` or `this.props` ?

Comment: this.props, I am updating the question as well'

Comment: any help on this

Comment: Without your code, I can't tell you why it doesn't work. But you can be sure that you cannot update the value `this.props` (read only).